# Error in storybook when using styled-component styling component

Tags: storybook

I am using storybook.
An error occurs if a styling component is included in the styled component in the storybook.

component/style.ts

```
import { Flex } from "rebass"

export const StyledFlex = styled(Flex)`
  // css...
`
```

storybook.mdx

```markdown
import { Meta, Story, Preview, Props } from "@storybook/addon-docs/blocks";
import { StyledFlex } from "component/style"

<Meta title="section/main" />

<Preview>
  <Story name="default">
    <StyledFlex/>
  </Story>
</Preview>
```

.storybook/main.js

```js
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require("tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  stories: [ //root setup is ok
],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-actions",
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.resolve.plugins = [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()];
    return config;
  },
};
```

error message

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

storybook version: 6.3.8
addons version: 6.3.8

using nextjs 10.0.6

Comment: Did you find any fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

This might fix your problem:

```js
// .storybook/preview.js
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import theme from '../src/ui/theme';

export const decorators = [
    Story => (
        <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
            <Story />
        </ThemeProvider>
    ),
];
```